# Emacs: don't show newline ($) whitespaces

Tags: emacs

I'm trying to set up Emacs for C++ programming. Currently I have following .emacs file:

```
(require 'cc-mode)
(global-linum-mode 1)
(setq indent-tabs-mode nil)
(setq tab-width 2)
(setq c-basic-offset 2)
(setq c-default-style "linux")
(define-key c-mode-base-map (kbd "RET") 'newline-and-indent)
(global-whitespace-mode 1)
(setq whitespace-space 'underline)
(setq whitespace-line-column 80)
(setq make-backup-files nil)
```

It shows whitespaces, but I can't find out how to turn off specific whitespaces. For example, $-symbols of a newline. For example:

```
#include·<iostream>$
using·namespace·std;$
$
int·main(int·argc,·char*·argv[])·{$
··return·0;$
}$
```

I've already tried options described in Emacs manuals. Is there an option to put into .emacs file to turn them off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `customize` (which is especially nice for new users),
add this to your customization:

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(whitespace-display-mappings
   '((space-mark 32 [183]
      [46])
     (space-mark 160 [164]
      [95])
     ;; (newline-mark 10 [36 10])
     (tab-mark 9 [187 9]
      [92 9]))))
```

I've commented out the part that shows newlines.
Alternatively, plain Elisp is:

```
(set-default
 whitespace-display-mappings
 '((space-mark 32 [183]
    [46])
   (space-mark 160 [164]
    [95])
   ;; (newline-mark 10 [36 10])
   (tab-mark 9 [187 9]
    [92 9])))
```

And just to show you how you could find this info:

1. <kbd>f1 f</kbd> `global-whitespace-mode`
2. follow the link to whitespace.el
3. <kbd>M-x</kbd> `occur` `\$` <kbd>RET</kbd>
4. This gives you 15 candidates, the one that's interesting
   is 9th on line 861.
5. Follow the link and read the doc for `whitespace-display-mappings`

Comment: `f1 f` calls `describe-function`.